# Canon MX870 Inkjet Printer prints blank pages

Tags: inkjet-printer

I have a Canon PIXMA MX870 printer. The issue is that it prints only blank pages when doing nozzle pattern checks.

I need to mention that I recognize this printer is old, and that this isn’t worth the time. Canon support told me to get a new printer. However, I would like to get this printer working.

This started with a ink absorber full error. The printer sat unused for 2-3 months. I took the printer apart, replaced the pads, re-assembled, and used the service tool to reset the ink counters in EEPROM.

After this, the printer starts up fine and appeared to be working, except that all pages came out blank. The printer is not connected to a computer, all prints are being done via maintenance menu (nozzle checks, cleaning). The pages all come out blank, except some occasional random ink puddles. I removed the printer head, thinking it may be clogged, and soaked it in isopropyl alcohol for a week. Wiped it clean, let it dry a few days, reinstalled, and still blank pages. Have tried nozzle check, cleaning cycled, nothing. When I remove ink cartridges after having done the head soak, I see wet ink again, so I have to think that the head/cartridges are getting the command to print (as opposed to something like the wired connection to them being broken).

Does this sound like it still has a clogged print head? Is there any way to check? I would like to try and get a bit more technical than “the printer has a hardware problem and should be serviced”. I would like to do the service/troubleshooting myself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/266034/how-can-i-solve-canon-mx870-printer-only-printing-blank-pages

Comment: Some guy on the internet says: "Yesterday I had removed the Printer and re-installed the drivers, but that didn't resolve the issue.  I noticed that there had been a couple of installations of the Printer (MX870), so I unstalled all instances of the printer, shutdown, started up, installed the Printer, now only having one instance of the MX870 and this configuration prints fine again."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve Canon MX870 printer only printing blank pages?](https://superuser.com/questions/266034/how-can-i-solve-canon-mx870-printer-only-printing-blank-pages)

Comment: Thanks all. I did search this forum and read those replies before posting. I realize they are similar, but this is not a new printer, so I was hoping to get a bit more technical than “the print head is genetically broken, replace the printer”. And again, it is not connected to a computer, so drivers are not the issue.

Comment: Did you do the manual print head alignment?

Comment: https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART106055